# Noun to describe a person whether easy or not to be influenced by others

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a noun to describe whether a person is easy or not to be influenced by others.
I think this noun should have the meaning of level in it.

For example, if I want to use a noun to describe whether a person has a huge impact on others, I can use the word "influence".

So, what is the right noun to describe the "to-be-influenced" level of a person.

Comment: You are looking for *easily influenced* or *not to be influenced* or ...?

Comment: @Jalene Thanks for your response. I actually need a noun to describe the level of a person whether he/she is easily influenced by others or not to be influenced by others. Just like my example, "influence" does not show whether a person is indeed influential or not, but it can be used to describe the level. Maybe some word with the meaning "be-influence" are appreciated ...

Comment: That person might be *impressionable*, *gullible*, *pliant*, *suggestible*, *a blank state*, or even *a sucker*.

Comment: A person can be stalwart in his convictions.

Comment: @MikeGraham Thanks for your response. These adjectives are helpful. But I'm looking for a noun.

Comment: While 'malleability' is gradeable ('wet clay has high malleability; set concrete extremely low malleability'), in its metaphorical sense it tends to be used for 'the fact / state of being easily influenced / trained' rather than 'how influentiable a person is'. Perhaps 'compliance' is a better choice here.

Comment: @MikeGraham Or *persuadable*.

Answer (score 1):

[impressionable](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/impressionable)/impressionability

e.g. Children usually have a higher impressionability than adults.

Comment: Could you explain why you believe the word is suitable? Perhaps you could cite a definition or usage example that suggests it fits the asker's needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a noun, and you don't mind idiom, there is "putty." One definition of this  malleable material: "one who is easily manipulated" (MW)

He is is putty in others' hands.

"Malleable" itself isn't bad if you'll settle for an adjective: One of the definitions: "one who is easily manipulated."